# Como abrir um Dialog a partir de um BaseAdapter no Android?

Tags: android, android-studio

tenho uma Button dentro de um BaseAdapter onde relaciona as ordens de produção de meu APP, o Onclick desse button deve abrir um Dialog com um novo baseadapter, mas está dando a seguinte exception:

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Criação do Dialog:

```
  DialogLotesPrensa mDialogLotesPrensa = new DialogLotesPrensa(mContext, ordem);
  mDialogLotesPrensa.show();
```

No evento onCreate do Dialog:

```
    public DialogLotesPrensa(Context context , Ordens ordem ) {
        super(context , R.style.Theme_Dialog);
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mOrdem = ordem;
        //this.mOnSelecionaLotePrensa = onSelecionaLotePrensa;
        this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_lista_series);
        this.setCancelable(false);
        this.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        setupDialogElements();
    }
```

A excetion está ocorrendo no super(context, R.style.Theme_Dialog);

Answer (score 0):

Voce precisa prover mais detalhes do adapter onde esta iniciando o dialog.

Mas respondendo um pouco, no android a maioria das funções relacionadas a UI precisam ser rodadas dentro da main thread. Logo é importante se certificar que está na main thread.

Voce poderia ter algumas opções no seu caso, uma delas seria tentar apenas notificar a view(activity/fragment) da ação de abrir dialog e ela cuida disso. Essa notificação poderia ser um callback por exemplo.

Outra opção seria voce usar o Handler, o handler no android permite a gente enfileirar ações para serem realizadas.
Ao iniciar o Handler podemos escolher em qual thread através do Looper.

Se voce tem acesso a activity poderia rodar a função runOnUiThread que também faz isso.

Ou voce poderia acessar a main Thread através do context d

```
ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(context).execute(()  -> {
        // This is where your UI code goes.
    }
```